# Why does MathJax character not work or get stuck in AngularJS sometimes?

Tags: angularjs, mathjax

I'm using MathJax's javascript library version 2.6.1 with an Angular 1.4 application. I have a page where I have multiple  tags that I call the same directive on, which calls MathJax.Hub.Queue("Typeset", MathJax.Hub, elem[0]) on the  tag. It seems the first item's characters get stuck on Preprocessing state (with gray preview text) and doesn't get fully processed to their final form.

On page load, I also call MathJax.Hub.Queue("Typeset", MathJax.Hub, document.body) and then it works fine. It's when the  tags are loaded from AngularJS that the first  tag gets stuck in Preprocessing state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question since I figured out a solution:

I spent a couple hours debugging the MathJax code and nothing seemed obviously wrong to be. I guessed it was MathJax's queue implementation not working well with AngularJS's scope watching. I was able to fix it after putting the `MathJax.Hub.Queue("Typeset", MathJax.Hub, elem[0])` inside a `$timeout(fn, 0)`.

The fixed directive ended up looking like this:

```
angular.module('xpl.widget').directive('mathjaxBind', mathjax);

/* ngInject */
function mathjax($timeout) {
    return {
        priority: 100,
        restrict: "A",
        link: {
            post: postLink
        }
    }

    // ## postLink
    function postLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            "HTML-CSS": {
                styles: {
                    ".MathJax_Display": {
                        "overflow-x": "auto"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.mathjaxBind, function (newVal, oldVal, scope) {
            // Add $timeout to MathJax Typesetting due to bug where first result wasn't getting queued properly. 
            $timeout(function() { 
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, elem[0]]);
            }, 0);
        });
    }

}
```